# Passing an MLMultiArray (or CGImage) to PencilKit so it can be edited

Tags: swiftui, coreml, pencilkit

Is it possible to initialize my PKCanvasView.drawing from an MLMultiArray or CGImage so that the user can edit it?

I have a semantic segmentation model that outputs the MLMultiArray of 1s (detected) and 0s (not-detected). I want the user to be able to edit the mask so they can submit corrections that could be used to improve the model, but for the life of me I can't understand how to make it so the segmentation mask can be edited. Any help is greatly appreciated. I know that the init method can be called with .init(from: Data), but can't seem to understand what format the Data needs to be in.

My struct is below, the rawArray is as described above, this throws: "Argument type 'Data' does not conform to type 'Decorder'"

struct pencilView: UIViewRepresentable {
var inputImage: UIImage
var rawArray: MLMultiArray
var colorModel: ColorModel
@Binding var drawingView: PKCanvasView

```
func updateUIView(_ uiView: PKCanvasView, context: Context) {
}


func makeUIView(context:Context) -> PKCanvasView {
    let length = rawArray.count
    let dblPtr = rawArray.dataPointer.bindMemory(to: Double.self, capacity: length)

    let dataOut = Data.init(bytes: dblPtr, count:length)
    drawingView.drawing = try! .init(from: dataOut)
    drawingView.drawingPolicy = .pencilOnly
    drawingView.tool = PKInkingTool(.pen, color: UIColor(colorModel.overlayColor), width: 15)
    return drawingView
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is how I solved my issue. First I realised that my maskArray is only in black (background) and white (detected). Then I can draw over the maskArray (using Drawsana), and only allow black (erase) and white (draw), from there I can overlay my mask and use .luminanceToAlpha()... so long as I make it a compositing group:

```
struct maskEdit: View {
    var maskImage: UIImage
    @Binding var eraseOn:Bool
    @Binding var slider: CGFloat
    var body: some View{
        ZStack {
            Image(uiImage:maskImage)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .clipped()
            drawsanaView(eraseOn: $eraseOn, slider: $slider)
        }
        .compositingGroup()
        .luminanceToAlpha()
    }
}

struct drawsanaView: UIViewRepresentable {
var drawView = DrawsanaView()
    @Binding var eraseOn: Bool
    @Binding var slider: CGFloat

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: Drawsana.DrawsanaView, context: Context) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            uiView.userSettings.strokeWidth = slider
            if eraseOn {
                uiView.userSettings.strokeColor = .white
            }
            else {
                uiView.userSettings.strokeColor = .black
            }
        }
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> DrawsanaView {
        let penTool = PenTool()
        drawView.set(tool: penTool)
    
        drawView.userSettings.strokeWidth = slider
        drawView.userSettings.fillColor = .clear
        drawView.userSettings.strokeColor = .white

        return drawView
    }
}
```

In my main view the maskEdit view can be multiplied by the user's chosen colour, and voila it is an editable mask :)